# Change Konsole title via Python

Tags: python, console, kde-plasma, konsole

How can I change the Konsole title in Python?
I found this code:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;test\x07")
```

But it only works with Gnome terminal, not Konsole (on Kubuntu).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would give `"\x1b]0;test\x07"` a try (note the `0` instead of `2`).

There is [an open bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231405) about Konsole not correctly treating xterm escape sequences; maybe it won't work at all until it is fixed.

Comment: Do you have command for Python 3? Is there any possible way rather than `os.system("echo -ne "\033]0;test\007"")`?

Answer (score 3):

```
dcop "$KONSOLE_DCOP_SESSION" renameSession "New title here"
```

This should work.  You can also run the command without the renameSession part to get a list of other options that you can changed.