# Is there a way to change the terminal title with curses?

Tags: python, curses

I'm searching for a way to change my terminal title with curses.

For now, I do it like this:

```
sys.stdout.write("\x1b]2;%s\x07" % title)
```

but I'm searching for a more general way to do it.

Comment: According to [the mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2004-04/msg00006.html), there is none (except maybe use `putp()`).

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but this is from 2004, it's a bit old. I was hoping this would be implemented now. :(

Comment: Sometimes the 2 needs to be replaced by 0 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919696/change-konsole-title-via-python

Comment: It's not part of the curses standard. PDCurses has PDC_set_title(), for some of its supported platforms.

Comment: I find sys.stdout.write fails to update the title at all. @FrédéricHamidi `putp()` just throws `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more general".  What you're asking for is a very system-specific task.  There's no reason to assume that there IS a terminal, much less how it works.  Windows contains a command line tool to change the terminal ("title").  The Unix derivatives use the ANSI sequences you have above.